# Segmentation fault when deleting all values in a binary search tree

Tags: segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

So I am having trouble running this function because it keeps returning a segmentation fault. I have narrowed it down to the "delete root;" line but don't know how to fix this error.

Any suggestions?

Here is the pre and postcondition included in the assignment:

> // Precondition: root is a pointer to the root of a binary search
>   tree.
>
> // Postcondition: The function deletes all nodes of the binary search
>   tree and sets // root to NULL.

```
template<class Key, class Item>
void tree_clear(bstNode<Item, Key>*& root)
{
bstNode<Item, Key>* child;
if(root != NULL)
{
    child = root->left();
    tree_clear(child);
    child = root->right();
    tree_clear(child);
    delete root;
    root = NULL;
 }
}
```

Comment: What is returned from ->left() and ->right() on the very deepest nodes? if those functions don't return NULL on the deepest node you might get the segfault.

Comment: Because your tree_clear requires a reference, isn't calling tree_clear(NULL) a bad thing?

Comment: He is checking for NULL. I'm thinking those functions might return some random pointer when called against the deepest nodes. Since that random pointer is not null, it tries to tree_clear it and delete it.

Comment: @akatakritos, isn't the check for NULL already too late?  It has already been assigned to the variable root.

Comment: Well I think that's the end case of the recursive function. If root is NULL, the function returns without doing anything and starts walking back up the stack. But, Stretch might be right below. If its a pointer to a reference, he might be setting the parent Node to NULL and then trying to delete it when it recurses back up. Its been too long since I did C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is a pointer to a reference... I think it should be a pointer to a pointer:

```
void tree_clear(bstNode<Item, Key>** root)
```

Comment: It still gives me a segmentation fault. I also can't really change the function prototype because our professor wants us to implement them. Any other ideas?

Comment: try delete *root; *root = NULL; ... and if you do that, you need to change your guard to if (*root == NULL) {}

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't change the signature, try

```
template<class Key, class Item>
void tree_clear(bstNode<Item, Key>*& root)
{
  bstNode<Item, Key>* child;
  if(root != NULL)
  {
    if (child = root->left()) {
       tree_clear(child);
    }
    if (child = root->right()) {
       tree_clear(child);
    }
    delete root;
  }
}
```